# Retrieve bean value from list of bean objects using JSP EL

Tags: java, jsp, el

Below is the request attribute set in struts action

```
ArrayList<HistoryTeardownHeader> list = new ArrayList<HistoryTeardownHeader>();
// add values to list 
request.setAttribute("tdbList",list);
```

Below i have shown how i am getting the list.I am not able to get the value weldtype from this line of code

```
<c:forEach var="post" items="${requestScope.tdbList}">
<c:out value="${ post.weldType}"></c:out>
<html:hidden property="currentWeld" value="${post.weldType}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

The below bean is declared in the HistoryTeardownHeader class.

```
private String weldType;

public String getWeldType() {
    return weldType;
}
public void setWeldType(String weldType) {
    this.weldType = weldType;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `${post['weldType']}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Guys!

The weldType property didnt fetch the value from DB correctly so it didnt reflect correctly.

So the EL code given above is actually correct and working fine!